# update table column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to `update` some column's value so i used this simple `query` but it doesn't work, can anyone suggest anything please ?

```
UPDATE 'tableA'
SET post_parent = (SELECT wp.ID FROM `tableA` wp 
                   WHERE wp.post_content='' AND wp.post_name='ba' AND wp.post_type='pa')    
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM `tableA` WHERE post_name like '%ba-%' AND post_type='pa')
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description, why doesn't it work? Don't quote a table name as if it's a string literal.

Comment: You should provide us a small dump of your table or at least the structure

Comment: could you please add sample data and expected output, either in question or in sqlfiddle ?

Comment: Your code doesn't even make sense if you try to fix the logic you have presented.  For instance, the subquery is likely to return multiple rows.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableA
SET post_parent = (SELECT wp.ID 
                   FROM tableA wp 
                   WHERE wp.post_content='' 
                   AND wp.post_name='ba' 
                   AND wp.post_type='pa')
WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID 
              FROM tableA 
              WHERE post_name 
              like '%ba-%' 
              AND post_type='pa')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not update a table where inner query or sub query with same table names.

Here you are updating `tableA` where in same query you are using `tableA` to get the result

[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Thanks